# What does it mean by "switch" in these context?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In many occurrences, I've seen the writer using the word "switch", for example:

If it mean "to whip", it would be odd.

Why does the writer insist on using this word?

> “I told you not to be a fool, Rand al’Thor. You may have Tairens
>   bowing to your boots, but I remember when Nynaeve **switched** your bottom
>   for letting Mat talk you into stealing a jar of apple brandy.”

> But if the Amyrlin had sent them somewhere, maybe they did. The Amyrlin
>   was capable of sending a woman into a bear’s den with nothing but a
>   **switch** if it suited her purposes. And she would expect the woman to
>   come back with a bearskin, or the bear on a leash, as instructed.

Comment: Sheesh.  You mean there's kids today who don't know this usage of the word from personal experience?  No wonder so many of them are so spoiled.

Comment: [Curse you, Spock!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Spock#Claims_that_Spock.27s_books_led_to_the_Anti_Vietnam_War_movement_and_Permissiveness)

Comment: OK....what happened just now? I am an non-native speaker. From my experience, the word switch is more likely to be referring to the electrical one. Anyway, I know the answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

In this context, it's a flexible branch used for inflicting punishment of the bottom-hitting kind. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_%28rod%29):

> A switch is a flexible rod, typically used for corporal punishment of the birching type, called **switching** after it.

It can either be a single branch, or sometimes [several branches together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvAxM.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

From Oxford English Dictionary -

> switch, n.
>
> A slender tapering riding whip.

And

> switch, v.
>
> To strike, hit, beat, flog, or whip with or as with a switch.

Comment: Yeah, this question is easily answered with a dictionary.